# touchesBegan is not called after releasing the UIView Object

Tags: objective-c, uiview, touchesbegan

I'm implementing an UIView with touchesBegan method.

When I create this UIView without releasing after add in subviews collection, all works fine.

But, when I'm a good citizen and I release the object after adding in subviews, the touches begans is not called.

This is my code:

Inserting UIViewController. OTTestResult is the Controller of the UIView:

```
-(void)validateWasPushed:(id)sender
{
    float nota = [testQuestions getTestResults];
    int ok = [testQuestions getOkNumber];
    int fail = [testQuestions getFailNumber];

    OTTestResult *result = [[OTTestResult alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:result.view];

    [result loadWithNumber:nota testName:[testQuestions testName] okResponses:ok failResponses:fail];


    [result release];

}
```

And touchesBegan implementation in OTTestResult object:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What class is self in this context? Is this code within a subclass of UIViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, when I'm a good citizen and I release the object after adding in subviews, the touches begans is not called.

You did not add `result` to `subviews`. You added `result.view`. You then released `result`, which no one else is holding, and it deallocated. You will need to hold onto the sub-view controller in an ivar if you need it to stay around.